# Xamarin.Forms iOS build Can't resolve the reference 'System.Drawing.RectangleF'

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have this error when building for Xamarin.Form.iOS

```
Can't resolve the reference 'System.Drawing.RectangleF', referenced from the method 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementTracker/<>c__DisplayClass29_0::<OnUpdateNativeControl>g__update|0()' in 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

and this is in output

```
Launch failed. The app 'MyApp.iOS' could not be launched on 'iPhone 6 iOS 12.0'. Error: error MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator: Could not find file "/Users/imac-nas01/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/...
```

I dont know how to solve it, im using the last version of Xamarin Form and VS2017.

Comment: As you use the  latest version of Xamarin.Forms . Which involves the Xamarin.iOS with version 13.x.x.x. But your Visual Studio 2017's Xamarin.iOS version doesn't match the version on Mac.The latest version for VS 2017 on Windows only has the Xamarin.iOS 12.x.x.x. So you could update the IDE to VS 2019 and make sure the version of Xcode is up to date (11.2.1).

Comment: yeah, im using the latest version of Xamarin.Forms and Xcode. But im using AnkhSVN which only have in VS2017, anyway thank for your support i will think of your suggestion